# randrange inside for loop in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please explain why the following code doesn't work.

```
import random
for x in random.randrange(100):
    print(x, end='')
    print()
for y in random.randrange(100):
    print(y, end='')
    print()
```

Comment: For one thing, `randrange()` takes 2 or 3 arguments. What output do you expect?

Comment: @TomZych: nope, one is enough.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Whoops, didn't read carefully.

Comment: Did you mean to include `print()` in the loop? You probably meant to unindent that and print the newline *after* the loop has completed. Otherwise you may as well drop it and drop the `end=''` argument.

Comment: And last but not least: don't just state that it *doesn't work*. What *should* happen when it *does* work? What output where you expecting?

Comment: Why have my question downgraded?

Comment: please provide feedback, and answer all the comments.  We are unsure what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.randrange()` returns **one integer**, taken from the given range. It does not produce an iterable sequence.

If you wanted to produce a `range()` iterable of random length, you need to pass the result of `randrange()` to `range()`, explicitly:

```
for x in range(random.randrange(100)):
```

Rather than use a loop, you can have `print()` print all values in one go:

```
print(*range(random.randrange(100)))
print(*range(random.randrange(100)))
```

The `*` syntax unpacks the `range()` iterable into separate arguments.

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> print(*range(random.randrange(100)))
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
>>> print(*range(random.randrange(100)))
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use range.

```
for x in range(random.randrange(100)):
```

Answer (score 1):

random.randrange() produces a number, which is not iterable.  You need to produce a list or some other iterable type as "y" in order to use "for x in y:"

You can use the range() function to do that.  Here, the range function produces a list of integer values from 0 up to 99, which you can iterate in a for loop:

```
for x in range(random.randrange(100)):
    print(x)
```